# Primary reasons for using REST/OData instead of a custom convention

Tags: rest, http, protocol

What do you think would be the primary reasons to make APIs with REST or OData instead of just making everything custom (for example only using GET requests, even for setting variables). Reasons for the opposite also welcome.

As a bit of background, it's going to be used for a request that is sent once every few minutes as a master-server updater for a game (as well as by clients for querying).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason is because you (attn buzzword bingo) fully leverage HTTP.

For example, if you only use GET requests, caches or proxies may get in the way, not (re)sending requests when you want to.

Using URLs to identify resources, means you can use all your favorite web-server tools, such as mod_rewrite.

Compare this to SOAP for example, which uses one URL and posts all requests there. That makes the URL useless. You cannot use log-file analysis tools to see which requests are popular, you need specific tools to do load testing, etc.

Answer (score 6):

**Because REST plays well with others.** When using a rest interface, you may use all the nice things that were invented for http. For example, you get load balancers, command line clients, traffic analysers more or less for free.
When implementing a custom protocol on top of TCP/IP, you have to write them yourself. When using HTTP 'incorrectly', the http-tools wont work correctly (for example, they could cache a get request you expect to have a side effect, or execute it preemptively)

Comment: and besides that: all the cool kids are doing it.

Comment: Great points, +1